# Какую хеш-функцию использовать для большого количества файлов?

Tags: java, файлы, хеширование

Нужно получить хеш всех файлов системы чтобы потом выявить дубликаты, какую хеш-функцию лучше всего использовать ?

Comment: Можете использовать любую. Вероятность коллизии пренебрежимо мала.

Comment: можете посмотреть здесь - http://stackoverflow.com/a/13209374/5292979

Comment: @s_klepcha Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вас беспокоит: производительность или возможность коллизии?

Comment: так это не ответ вовсе, а комментарий. А вообще то вы правы.  Хорошо

Comment: @NickVolynkin производительность и низкий шанс коллизии - хочу золотую середину

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вы не возьмёте совсем уж адский алгоритм, то скорость хэширования кучи файлов будет упираться в скорость чтения с жёсткого диска, а не в производительность хэширующей функции. Если даже вы параноик, берите хоть SHA-512. Вероятность случайной коллизии близка к нулю, даже если целую галактику заполнить жёсткими дисками с различными файлами, а скорость хорошей реализации в районе 150-200 Мб/с на одно ядро процессора. Старый добрый MD5 в несколько раз быстрее.

Если ваша задача выявить дубликаты в наборе файлов, для начала стоит отсортировать их по длине. Файлы с разной длиной очевидно разные. Все файлы, у которых длина уникальная, выкидывайте из сравнения сразу, хэш-функции не считайте. Далее считаем, что мы сравниваем файлы одинаковой длины.

Если файлов с одинаковой длиной всего два, не стоит считать хэш-функцию от каждого. Можно сразу открыть оба и сравнить их содержимое. Если они отличаются близко к началу, вы сразу обнаружите это. В этом случае вы можете сэкономить кучу времени: для подсчёта хэш-функции вам пришлось бы читать оба файла целиком. Если же файлы совпали, вы по факту тоже не теряете, потому что файлы читать всё равно бы пришлось.

Если файлов с одинаковой длиной несколько, тут следует прикинуть, с какой вероятностью вы ожидаете совпадающие файлы. Если их ожидается мало, то, возможно, эффективнее сравнивать первый со вторым, третьим и т. д. как выше, чем считать хэш-функции. Если повторы вероятны, то хэш-функции всё же помогут. Тут ещё стоит подумать, надо ли хэшировать весь файл. Каковы шансы, что у файлов с одинаковой длиной первый мегабайт, например, полностью совпадает, а дальше различия идут? Если такие шансы не очень велики (скажем, меньше 50%), хэшируйте только первый мегабайт, а в случае совпадения уже проверяйте, что там дальше.

Тут больше следует оптимизировать чтение с диска, чем подсчёт хэш-функции (если чтение с диска не делает за вас библиотека, считающая хэш). В таких случаях, конечно же, рекомендуется использовать [memory-mapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29).